# Chrome - Refresh waits ajax request's end - long polling

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-polling

I've a long polling request for a chat in my website. The request lasts 30s and is called again when the response is received.

When time I refresh the page (ctrl + R), chrome seems to wait until the end of the ajax call, it can last up to 29.99s.

I tried to bind an event on the 'unload' event, but it is sent after the end of the ajax call.

Is there a way to say the web client to "stop all requests", thus allowing to refresh normally in a few seconds the page.

Comment: Ok in fact I forgot to write 'session_write_close()' in the long-polling request. The problem wasn't due to chrome, but to the server side which was bloqued until the php session was unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is assign your ajax request to a variable and on window onload event abort them.

```
var myAjax = $.ajax(...);
window.onunload = function(){ 
 if(typeof myAjax!=='undefined') {
   myAjax.abort();
 }
}
```

Comment: `onunload` is triggered after the end of the ajax call, as I specified in the post. It doesn't work.

Comment: In fact no onunload is triggered when the request to the next page is finished.